# Killing the background window when running a .exe from a Python program

Tags: python, executable

the following is a line from a python program that calls the "demo.exe" file. a window for demo.exe opens when it is called, is there any way for demo.exe to run in the "background"? that is, i don't want the window for it show, i just want demo.exe to run.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args = "demo.exe", stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
```

the output of demo.exe is used by the python program in real time, so demo.exe is not something that i can have run in advance of running the python program. demo.exe handles a lot of on the fly back-end calculations. i'm using windows xp.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016384/cross-platform-subprocess-with-hidden-window), I think this is what you need:

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
p = subprocess.Popen(args = "demo.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

I tested on my Python 2.6 on XP and it does indeed hide the window.

Comment: If you set `STARTF_SHOWWINDOW`, you will also want to initialise the `wShowWindow` member of `startupinfo` to one of the `SW_*` constants. This method relies on the program that you run actually acting upon the `wShowWindow` flag; it's not required to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STARTUPINFO, STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
p = Popen(cmdlist, startupinfo=startupinfo, ...)
```

Comment: If you set `STARTF_SHOWWINDOW`, you will also want to initialise the `wShowWindow` member of `startupinfo`. This method relies on the program that you run actually acting upon the `wShowWindow` flag; it's not required to do so.

Comment: i upvoted both answers and flipped a coin for best answer, ewall won.

Comment: Ah well.  I got my answer in first (by 8 minutes, no less!) and I still don't get the points. :-)  No worries, ewall needs the upvotes more than I do.

Comment: ah, sorry, i didn't pay attention to time. still new here.