# extracting git time recursivley for subfolders and files

Tags: python, git, python-2.x, gitpython

I am trying to create  a dictionary with elements in the  format filename: timestamp  in yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss   . This should  recursively include  all subfolders  and files  in the  repo  .  I came  across  ths  piece of code :

```
import git
repo = git.Repo("./repo")
tree = repo.tree()
for blob in tree:
    commit = repo.iter_commits(paths=blob.path, max_count=1).next()
    print(blob.path, commit.committed_date)
```

However, this   includes  only  the  main  sub folders. How  to  include  sub folders and files  recursively

Note:  The   following solution by Roland here  does not include sub folders, only files.Also I need   to be in the  path where git repo  is  downloaded and then  run the script by giving its absolute path

[Get time of last commit for Git repository files via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104495/get-time-of-last-commit-for-git-repository-files-via-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This   works   for me

http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-tree-object

As per  the doc As trees allow direct access to their intermediate child entries only, use the traverse method to obtain an iterator to retrieve entries recursively

It creates  a generator object  which does the  work

```
print tree.traverse()
<generator object traverse at 0x0000000004129DC8>




  d=dict()
  for blob in tree.traverse():
        commit=repo.iter_commits(paths=blob.path).next()
           d[blob.path]=commit.committed_date
```