# multiprocessing in Maya pops up a window

Tags: python, multiprocessing, maya

I am writing a plugin for Maya 2011 using python. To utilize all the cores available in my machine (running Windows 7 32-bit) and speed up the performance of the plugin, I created multiple processes using multiprocessing module. when the processes are created, the output window pops up (which initially pops up when launching Maya). To solve this problem i read [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/python_inside_maya@googlegroups.com/msg07086.html) discussion. When I set mayapy.exe as executable, as the new process is created using multiprocessing.Process(...), another window pops up (looking like a command line window). The number of widows is same as the number of processes, these windows just appeared and vanished as the processes end up with their execution.
I can't understand the reason of appearing these small windows, I don't want these windows to pop up, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using subprocess.Popen in Maya
If you pass startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow.SW_HIDE to the Popen constructor, this hides the command line subprocess window.
read :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I am guessing the same **might** be true of multiprocessing.Process, although I am not at a Windows box right now to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to spawn separate copies of MayaPy using the subprocess flags as per @tranimatronic's answer.  The exact flags depend on your OS:

[Cross-platform subprocess with hidden window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016384/cross-platform-subprocess-with-hidden-window)

However, you will probably have problems if you try to share scene information among your processes: each one is a completely separate copy of Maya. If it's a big batch job and you can share a read-only file (for example, you want to render out portions of animation or bake lights one at at time) that will work, but you won't be able to do parallel processing in the same scene (for example, creating geometry).  In general, if you're doing something so computationally intensive that you really care about multiple cores in Maya, you'll probably have better luck with the C++ API.

Also: be watch out for the fact that the [default maya version of subprocess doesn't use pipes like ordinary python:](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2170-Python-subprocess-Popen%28%29-questions)

Answer (score -1):

The typical way of preventing python from popping up console windows is to add a 'w' to the end of the filename "mypythonfile.pyw"