# Hide console with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, windows, macos, subprocess

I'm new to `subprocess.Popen` and have been reading the docs. I'm just trying to make my process not open a console. Which of these parameters do I need?

```
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
shell=False,
creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

Will this only work for Windows? Do I need to do something different for it to work on Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that on POSIX platforms (like a Mac) you're not going to actually see a console under any circumstances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-platform subprocess with hidden window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016384/cross-platform-subprocess-with-hidden-window)

Comment: It doesn't talk about my parameters in that question, just some other `startupinfo`. Would appreciate someone shedding some light.

Comment: I added an answer that directly addresses all the arguments you listed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`stdout=subprocess.PIPE` has no effect on whether or not a console appears. It just determines whether or not the `stdout` of the subprocess is captured in a pipe that you can read from or not.

`shell=False` is the default for all `subprocess` commands, so you don't need to provide it. It tells `subprocess` whether or not to use a shell to execute the provided command. It does not have any effect on whether or not a console appears on any platform.

`creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW` will indeed hide the console on Windows (tested on Windows 7, assuming `CREATE_NO_WINDOW == 0x08000000`). It will cause an error to use it on non-Windows platforms, though. You should reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016384/cross-platform-subprocess-with-hidden-window) for a way to only provide `creationflags` on Windows, and also for alternative way to hide the console.

Note that the console appearing should only be an issue on Windows. On Posix platforms the console shouldn't ever appear when running subprocesses.