# How to hide Chromedriver console window?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, console

I have a simple Python script which uses selenium and webdriver to open up Facebook in a Chrome window and log in automatically. 
When I run it, the Chromedriver console window opens up and stays open even after the entire program has finished execution, until I close it myself.

Is there a way to hide this console window? I have tried keeping a ".pyw" extension for my script, but that doesn't help since it's not the script's console window but the Chromedriver subprocess' console window that I wish to hide.

I couldn't find any resources on this. I think I might need to modify the chrome webdriver source code, but I don't know how. This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")

email = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
passwd = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")

email.clear()
passwd.clear()

email.send_keys("example@example.com")
passwd.send_keys("examplepassword")

passwd.submit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`driver.quit()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver.quit) at the end of the script:

> `quit()`
>
> Closes the browser and shuts down the ChromeDriver executable
>   that is started when starting the ChromeDriver

If you want to just close the service executable and let the browser stay opened, call:

```
driver.service.stop()
```

FYI, I've figured this out from the `quit()` method implementation ([source code](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py#71)).

Comment: Tried that; it closes the browser too! :/

Comment: @AkshayDamle hm, you want the browser to stay opened but close the chrome driver executeable service?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to achieve

Comment: Thanks, this works! But now what if I want to use Chromedriver again later on [if I'm writing a dynamic program], I will have to create a webdriver again, use it, and then quit it. So the console window will pop open and close. But I don't want this, I only want to hide the console instead of stopping the service altogether. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @AkshayDamle I see, then I guess passing `startupinfo` to the `subprocess.Popen` (as [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016651/771848)) should solve the issue. But, since the service startup is hidden inside the [`Service` class implementation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py#60), you would need to monkey-patch it.

Answer (score 4):

To hide the webdriver console window, I had to edit the Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\services.py in my case but I was using PhantomJS. PhantomJS imports and uses this file to start its process. Basically, I added the following creation flag to the Start method:

```
def start(self):
    """
    Starts the Service.

    :Exceptions:
     - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
       or when it can't connect to the service
    """
    try:
        cmd = [self.path]
        cmd.extend(self.command_line_args())
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
                                        close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows',
                                        stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
    except TypeError:
        raise` in bold.
```

Also add to the imports this line `from win32process import CREATE_NO_WINDOW`

This should also work for the Chrome webdriver, as its service.py also imports this very same file, though I have not had time to try.

Comment: Dude you save lives. Works like a charm in 2018.This freaking console was an nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but when I run `driver.service.stop()` it closes Chrome. I worked around it by importing os and firing off a task kill to the chrome process.

This is another option: first change script extension from `.py` to `.pyw`, then:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/apps/chromedriver.exe', service_args=["--verbose", '--log-path=c:/logs/logs/qc1.log'])

driver.get("https://example.com")

switch = driver.find_element_by_id("signInSbmtBtn")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
username = driver.find_element_by_id("userid")
username.send_keys('user');
password.send_keys('password');
switch.click();

os.system("taskkill /im chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me! This works if you need a completely windowless program (For example: if you need a sample of cookies). So no console output and no browser window

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-startup-window')
```

Here is a sample of how you would do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-startup-window')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")

print(driver.get_cookies())
```

And also uh.. Make the python file a .pyw one instead of a .py to make its console window headless too (just rename it!)