# python requests sometimes returns empty list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, lxml, screen-scraping

So I've been trying to scrape the "2005 - 2013" from the "Drink Between 2005 2013"
and at first this code worked for me but now I only get empty lists returned, yet my requests still have a 200 status code

```
import requests, lxml.html, csv
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get('http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?
iWine=91411',headers=headers)
print(page.status_code)
html = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
content_divs = html.xpath('//a[@title="Source: Community"]/text()')
print(content_divs)
```

not sure if I should start using selenium to do this scraping because it's a js site, and if so not sure how to do that either so some basic help would be useful!
Thanks!!

Comment: If it's a js site, definitely you need to use `Selenium` or similar tool to scrape it

Comment: I get the expected result, not sure why it would stop working, are you trying to parse the same website over and over ang get an empty list sometimes? If you want a reference to using `Selenium` for scraping, I just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45315393/5103802) a question with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=91411"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver2.25")
driver.get(url)
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(.,'review')]")
for item in list:
    print(item.text)
    print("---")
```

Output:

```
Options
1/4/2014 - REUBENSHAPCOTT WROTE:
91 Points
Delicious! Had no idea that Australia made port this good, and affordable. Terrific, smooth fig and plum. Aged and neither sharp nor grapey. If you see it, buy it.
Do you find this review helpful? Yes - No / Comment
---
Options
1/20/2013 - LISAADAM WROTE:
85 Points
The wine looks Tawny colored.
Do you find this review helpful? Yes - No / Comment
---
Options
12/22/2012 - WINEAGGREGATE LIKES THIS WINE:
90 Points
Molasses, pepper, butterscotch candy that's been roasted a bit. Very nice.
Do you find this review helpful? Yes - No / Comment
---
Options
10/30/2011 - GTI2TON WROTE:
87 Points
Sweeter than average tawny and straightforward, but still has nice richness in its raisin and light carmel notes. Good value.
Do you find this review helpful? Yes - No / Comment
```