# Close console but leave selenium browser open

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried each of these solutions to no avail in attempt to achieve the same thing that was discussed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871898/how-to-hide-chromedriver-console-window/25871933#). Yet that console window sticks around.

```
#kill console through .system
import os, sys
#webbrowsing modules
from selenium import webdriver

#function to launch browser in chrome
def launch_chrome(page):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\cj9250\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\chromedriver.exe')
    browser.get(page)
    return browser

url = "https://www.google.com/"

browser = launch_chrome(url)

#prints 'SUCCESS: The process "chromedriver.exe" with PID 9872 has been terminated.'
#in the terminal and leaves it open
os.system('taskkill /F /im chromedriver.exe')

quit()
#never gets to this print command
print('it quit')

#closes the browser as well
browser.service.stop()

sys.exit
print('it exit')
```

I should note that I am running my programs from batch files called by win+r similar to the way described in [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/appendixb/). I also am running Python through Anaconda.

Comment: have you tried taskkil python.exe?

Comment: Why are you trying to call **quit()** after forcefully killing **chromedriver.exe**? What is your _usecase_ exactly?

Comment: I should note that I have tried each of the three solutions on the bottom individually, commenting the others out. By usecase are you asking more details on what I'm trying to do exactly?

I will attempt taskkill python.exe and report back.

Comment: Killing python produces a similar result to chromedriver, the console stays open and reports that python has been successfully killed.