# How to run .vbs or .bat from python without a black console window?

Tags: python

I need to run .bat (or .vbs) many times (in a loop in .py) and a "black window" do the process more slowly. 
How can I avoid that?

Comment: This is probably a Superuser question Python does not control the .bat file it just executes it if you provide the code

Comment: If you're using `subprocess`, one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7006238/, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1016384/.

Comment: @senshin thank you, it works